# How to switch theme for one page only in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way we can change to a specific theme for a specific page only in Wordpress?

I tried easy theme switcher but the problem with that is that it changes theme permanently.

I don't want that...

Answer (score 6):

I am not 100% sure of exactly what you want to achieve - but if it is only to have a different display for a single page (rather then really change ALL the theme to include all the functions etc..) , then -

You should can create a [page-template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) and then choose it in the drop-down menu for your page .

(in the sidebar - Page-attributes ->Template)

In that case , you could also use specific functions by adding them to the page itself (before the output.)

For example :

```
<?php
    /*
    Template Name: my-page-name
    */
    function my_specific_page_function() {
    //..do_whatever
    }
?>
```

Comment: Agreed. Don't use a theme for a single page. Create a custom page template. You don't need to use the common header either. You could just write the whole code in HTML and CSS after the template name lines.

Answer (score 0):

There is this plugin but it hasn't been updated in over a year

http://wordpress.org/plugins/page-theme/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free plugin Freesoul Switch Theme, both for debugging and in a permanent way